# Nuxt Auth Redirect Me Back to Login Page After Refresh Even a Successfull Login

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js, laravel-passport

I'm using **@nuxt/auth** module with Laravel Passport I'm facing a problem when a I attempt to login it logged me in successfully but when I refresh the page it redirect me back to login page I checked the cookies and it's set and has the token but i don't why this is happening?
Login.vue

```
<template>
  <v-parallax
    dark
    :src="require(`../assets/images/auth-bg.jpg`)"
    height="100%"
  >
    <v-app id="app-container" dark>
      <v-container fill-height fluid>
        <v-card
          class="mx-auto"
          justify="center"
          width="512"
          max-width="512"
          elevation="2"
          outlined
        >
          <v-form
            ref="form"
            v-model="valid"
            lazy-validation
          >
            <v-card-title>Login</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.username"
                :counter="32"
                type="text"
                label="Username"
                name="usermame"
                required
              />
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.password"
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                required
              />
            </v-card-text>
            <v-alert
              v-if="error"
              border="left"
              close-text="Close Alert"
              color="#C51162"
              dark
              dismissible
            >
              {{ error }}
            </v-alert>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-btn
                block
                outlined
                shaped
                @click="loginPassport"
              >
                Login
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-form>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </v-parallax>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'auth',
  auth: 'guest',
  data: () => ({
    valid: false,
    loader: null,
    loading: false,
    usernameRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Username is required',
      v => v.length <= 32 || 'Name must be less than 32 characters'
    ],
    passwordRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Password is required',
      v => v.length <= 32 || 'Password must be less than 32 characters'
    ],
    form: {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    },
    error: null
  }),
  watch: {
    loader () {
      const status = this.loader
      this[status] = !this[status]
      setTimeout(() => (this[status] = false), 500)
      this.loader = null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async loginPassport () {
      this.error = null

      await this.$auth
        .loginWith('DersTVCentral', { data: this.form })
        .then(() => this.$router.push('/'))
        .catch(() => (this.error = 'Incorrect email or password.'))
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app-container {
  background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
```

Nuxt.config.js

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - DersTV-Cloud-UI',
    title: 'DersTV-Cloud-UI',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // runtime config
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    apiURL: process.env.API_URL
  },
  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    apiId: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID,
    apiSecret: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],

  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
  },

  proxy: {
    '/backend': {
      target: process.env.API_URL,
      pathRewrite: { '^/backend': '/' }
    }
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  },

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      home: '/profile'
    },
    cookie: {
      options: {
        secure: false
      }
    },
    strategies: {
      DersTVCentral: {
        name: 'DersTVCentral',
        provider: 'laravel/passport',
        url: '/backend',
        endpoints: {
          user: 'api/v1/user',
          userInfo: 'api/v1/user'
        },
        responseType: 'token',
        clientId: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grantType: 'password'
      }
    }
  },
  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

Screenshot of successfull login:
[image]

Comment: Someone can have any solution?

Comment: Were you able to find the problem? As I am experiencing the same situation.